# In MacPorts, how to identify and uninstall unused library ports?

Tags: macos, macports

Lots of ports in macports are installed as library dependencies of the other (application) ports, but uninstall those application ports doesn't uninstall corresponding library dependencies.  As time goes by, lots of such library ports become orphon and is just a waste of space.  So I wonder if there is a way to find them out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package/script you need called port_cutleaves.
I think it's available directly from macports or fink.
Either way your problem is orphaned dependencies, and this should remove them, sorry I don't have details of usage as I'm away from my macports install.

Update: This link might help you, it's a cheat sheet.
http://www.jbmurphy.com/2011/02/17/my-mac-ports-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 6):

To remove inactive port you can run

`sudo port uninstall inactive`

To remove from version 2.4 and upper you can run

`sudo port reclaim`

> > The reclaim action attempts to reclaim space by uninstalling inactive ports, and removing unnecessary files that were downloaded during the installation process.

Answer (score 2):

As new versions of ports get installed, old versions are changed to an inactive state but remain on the disk. To see these ports:

`port list inactive`

To remove all inactive ports:

`[[ -z "$(port -q list inactive)" ]] || sudo port uninstall inactive`

This does not remove active versions of any port, including ports that were only needed during the build of a specific port. As @Mitchell Currie mentioned, use `port_cutleaves` if you want to remove those active ports.

Comment: port installed inactive